# Click on a link having a href attribute within <li>

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on a Login Link but the system throws noSuchElementException.
i have tried xpaths as well but i am unable to click on the login button and i am attaching the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

class CreateAccount:

def signUp(self):

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("http://www.scrumdo.com")
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/account/signup']").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys("Rockyhandsome")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='fullname']").send_keys("Naqash Zafar")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']").send_keys("naqash.zafar@kualitatem.com")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("k12345678")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()

CA = CreateAccount()
CA.signUp()
```

Trace back details

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/naqash.zafar/PycharmProjects/Assignments/CreateAccountOnScrumdo.py", line 38, in <module> CA.signUp()
    File "C:/Users/naqash.zafar/PycharmProjects/Assignments/CreateAccountOnScrumdo.py", line 15, in signUp        browser.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
    File "C:\Users\naqash.zafar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in find_element_by_link_text
        return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
    File "C:\Users\naqash.zafar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 744, in find_element
        {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
    File "C:\Users\naqash.zafar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "C:\Users\naqash.zafar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Login"}
    Stacktrace:
        at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/NAQASH~1.ZAF/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpiln2m889/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
        at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///C:/Users/NAQASH~1.ZAF/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpiln2m889/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/NAQASH~1.ZAF/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpiln2m889/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/NAQASH~1.ZAF/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpiln2m889/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/NAQASH~1.ZAF/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpiln2m889/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you paste html element which you are trying to click ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the menu dropdown then select the login button:

```
class CreateAccount:

    def signUp(self):

        browser = webdriver.Firefox()

        browser.get("http://www.scrumdo.com")

        menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='navbar-toggle']")
        menu.click()
        time.sleep(.25)

        menu.find_element_by_xpath("//li/a[@mixpanel='Homepage Clicked Login']").click()

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/account/signup']").click()
        time.sleep(.25)

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']").send_keys("Rockyhandsome")

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='fullname']").send_keys("Naqash Zafar")

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']").send_keys("naqash.zafar@kualitatem.com")

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys("k12345678")

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The page contains some dynamic contents which needs to be synchronised with a waiter.
Moreover, you need to set the size of the window since the type of layout can change depending on width :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

browser.set_window_size(1280, 768)
browser.get("http://www.scrumdo.com")

# click login
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[.='Login']"))).click()

# wait for the login button
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginButton")))

# click signup
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/account/signup']").click()

# wait for the signup form
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "signupForm")))

# fill the form
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=username]").send_keys("name")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=fullname]").send_keys("password")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=email]").send_keys("na@na.na")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=password]").send_keys("na")
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()
```